# Landsat 5 EVI in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, evi

I used this script for Landsat 8 and it worked fine, I've changed the band info for Landsat 5 but now I get this error:

```
ImageCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=0):
Image.select: Pattern 'B4' did not match any bands.
```

Where am I going wrong?

```
// Import landsat imagery. Create function to cloud mask from 
// the pixel_qa band of Landsat 5 SR data. 
// Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.

var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterBounds(AOI);
   
function maskL8sr(imageCollection) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 3;
  var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 5;
   
  var qa = imageCollection.select('pixel_qa');

  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));

  return imageCollection.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B[0-9]*")
      .copyProperties(imageCollection, ["system:time_start"]);
}

var stepList = ee.List.sequence(2000,2012);
 
var filterCollection = stepList.map(function(year){
  var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year,3,1);
  var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year,5,31);
  var composite_i = imageCollection.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                        .map(maskL8sr)
                        .median()
                        .set('system:time_start',startDate);
  return composite_i;
});

print(filterCollection)
var yearlyComposites = ee.ImageCollection(filterCollection);
print(yearlyComposites, 'Masked and Filtered Composites');
 

 // Add Enhanced Vegetation Index to a function and apply it.
 // EVI = 2.5 * ((NIR - Red) / (NIR + 6 * Red – 7.5 * Blue + 1))
 function evi(img){
   var eviImg = img.select(['B4','B3','B1'],['nir','red','blue']);
   eviImg = eviImg.expression(
     '(2.5 * ((NIR - RED)) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
       'NIR': eviImg.select('nir'),
       'RED': eviImg.select('red'),
       'BLUE': eviImg.select('blue')
     }).rename('EVI');
   return img.addBands(eviImg);
 }
 
 yearlyComposites = yearlyComposites.map(function(image){
   return evi(image);
 });
 
 print(yearlyComposites, 'With EVI as Band');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `stepList.map(...)` function is returning some images with no bands (and therefore no band names `B4`, `B3`, `B2` that the `evi` function is looking for).

[image]

Here I have added a `valid` property to each image in the collection based on whether it has bands, then filter the collection on that property.

```js
// Import landsat imagery. Create function to cloud mask from 
// the pixel_qa band of Landsat 5 SR data. 
// Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.

var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterBounds(AOI);
   
function maskL8sr(imageCollection) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 3;
  var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 5;
   
  var qa = imageCollection.select('pixel_qa');

  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));

  return imageCollection.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B[0-9]*")
      .copyProperties(imageCollection, ["system:time_start"]);
}

// cloud masking outside the stepList.map() function for efficiency
var imageCollectionMasked = imageCollection.map(maskL8sr);

var stepList = ee.List.sequence(2000,2012);
 
var filterCollection = stepList.map(function(year){
  var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year,3,1);
  var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year,5,31);
  var composite_i = imageCollectionMasked.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                        .median()
                        .set('system:time_start', startDate);
  
  // add a 'valid' property of 1 if image has bands and 0 if image has no bands
  // it works because a populated list is evaluated as true and an empty list is evaluated as false
  composite_i = ee.Algorithms.If(composite_i.bandNames(), composite_i.set('valid', 1), composite_i.set('valid', 0))
  
  return composite_i;
});


// make an image collection from list of images
var yearlyComposites = ee.ImageCollection(filterCollection);

// filter only valid images
yearlyComposites = yearlyComposites.filterMetadata('valid', 'equals', 1);

print(yearlyComposites, 'Masked and Filtered Composites');
 

 // Add Enhanced Vegetation Index to a function and apply it.
 // EVI = 2.5 * ((NIR - Red) / (NIR + 6 * Red – 7.5 * Blue + 1))
 function evi(img){
   var eviImg = img.select(['B4','B3','B1'],['nir','red','blue']);
   eviImg = eviImg.expression(
     '(2.5 * ((NIR - RED)) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
       'NIR': eviImg.select('nir'),
       'RED': eviImg.select('red'),
       'BLUE': eviImg.select('blue')
     }).rename('EVI');
   return img.addBands(eviImg);
 }
 
 yearlyComposites = yearlyComposites.map(function(image){
   return evi(image);
 });
 
 print(yearlyComposites, 'With EVI as Band');
```